# trying to list the most "voted on" messages with a specific reaction emoji on them

Tags: python, discord.py

Trying to do a thing where you enter a command and get a list of the top 5 messages with a reaction emoji called :goldmedal: . when entered into the bot, everything is fine, but when executing the command it starts a infinite loop of responses to every message it can find. and doesn't show the "goldmedal" value, but rather all the reactions on that specific message. https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/511938736594878478/512733361819746314/unknown.png

```
import discord
from discord import Game
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord import Channel
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands

bot = Bot(command_prefix='!')


    def num_reactions(message):
        return sum(react_count for react in message.reactions)

    @bot.command(pass_context=True)
    async def most_reacted(ctx, channel: Channel):
        most_reactions = most_reactions_message = None
        goldmedal_emoji = get(ctx.message.server.emojis, name="goldmedal_emoji")
        async for message in bot.logs_from(channel):
            num_reactions_message = ([goldmedal_emoji])
            num_reactions_message = num_reactions(message)
            if not most_reactions or num_reactions_message > most_reactions:
                most_reactions = num_reactions_message
                most_reactions_message = message
                await bot.say(f"{most_reactions_message.content} has the most Gold Medals with {most_reactions}")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  "Doesn't work out much" isn't a problem *specification*.  Your posted example needs some support code.

Answer (score 0):

Your function here:

```
def num_reactions(message):
    return sum(react_count for react in message.reactions)
```

only fetches the number of different reactions to a message instead of the count of reactions with the goldmedal emoji. You would probably want something like this instead:

```
def num_reactions(message):
    for react in message.reactions:
        if react.emoji.name === "goldmedal_emoji":
            return react.count
```

There are also many long term issues with your approach being:

1. It only obtains the last 100 messages from the log as the default limit of logs_from() is 100 (unless this is exactly what you want)
2. The bot has to search the channel every single time the command is ran which will be SLOW

May I suggest a different approach that stores the highest 5 in memory (hopefully not RAM but a database, or other persistent storages such as text files, in case your bot ever crashes), replacing them instead when a new message has a higher count of "goldmedal_emoji" reactions.